# Drag And Drop a panels in WebPage using javascript ,css, html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to this JQuery, I need two panels to be draggable each other, i can able to move panel2 in to panel 1 but i cannot able to movie panel1 in to panel 2 can any 1 please find my issue here

http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/74SHy/

Comment: There you go. http://jsfiddle.net/74SHy/2/

Comment: You are mistaken, i want to drag whole panel now "Text", i want to drag PANEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya  **see  working demo here** : http://jsfiddle.net/74SHy/59/

Very good question; so the issue is `tolerance` and adding this line will fix your issue `tolerance: 'pointer',` I can explain more but I think all the events are documented here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-tolerance

**Jquery Code**

```
  // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
         containment: 'parent',
          handle : '.handle',
          tolerance: 'pointer',
          update : function () {
          var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
       }
    });
});


​
```

This will help, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the handle option:

http://jsfiddle.net/74SHy/23/

new code :

```
 $("#test-list").sortable({
     containment: 'parent',
    //removed the handle
      update : function () {
      var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
   }
});
```

Comment: Still it is not working, it moving from botton panel not from upper panel. from 1st panel to second panel it is not moving, from second panel to first panel it is moving